# Using oninput with CodeMirror

Tags: javascript

When my textarea was just a textarea, oninput was  firing my function. Now that I have transformed the textarea into a CodeMirror, I cant get the console.log() to register.

This is how I used the CodeMirror

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("textArea"), {
mode: "javascript",
lineNumbers: true,
lineWrapping: true,
theme : 'monokai'
});
```

Here is the textarea with oninput functionality

```
<textarea id="textArea" oninput="return myKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
```

Here is my function that should be called by oninput

```
function myKeyPress(e) {
    socket.emit('textAreaText', document.getElementById('textArea').value);
    console.log("first emit");
  }
```

How can I get this function to run when the textarea receives input?

Comment: the "change" event seems to be working for me: `editor.on("change", () => { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but this is working for me, I commented the socket because I cant define it on fiddle:

```
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("textArea"), {
 mode: "javascript",
 lineNumbers: true,
 lineWrapping: true,
 theme : 'monokai'
});
function myKeyPress(e){
//socket.emit('textAreaText', document.getElementById('textArea').value);
 console.log("first emit");
}
</script>
<textarea id="textArea" oninput="return myKeyPress(event)"></textarea>
```

[Here the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqyfLLnq/)

Comment: It looks like that is working because JSFiddle skips the whole Code Mirror thing and you just have a normal textarea